# Partial result in PocketSphinx

Tags: android, colors, speech-recognition

I have an app running with pocketsphinx (the demo that comes with it). My app needs to be be 
able to for example change change a color when commanded to.
Sort of the "hello world" on sphinx4 with "color black/blue" instead of "hello phillip"

I have slightly modified the pocketsphinxandroiddemo to do so.

When using the button to recognize I could achieve the actions by using this in the run() of OnResult:

```
        if(hyp.equals("COLOR BLACK")){

                bg.setImageResource(R.drawable.black);

                }
                if(hyp.equals("COLOR WHITE")){
                bg.setImageResource(R.drawable.white);

                }
```

No problems there.

But I need continuous listening so I bypassed the button and went to my OnPartial run() instead.
There the   .equals("KEY WORD") didn't work so I used .contains("KEY WORD").
And that works as long as I change down through my if-statements but not up through them because my hyp or something still contains previous words and thus executes the last commands in my switches.

Question: How do I clear the hyp after well-performed action?

This is my OnPartial:

> public void onPartialResults(Bundle b) {

```
    final PocketSphinxAndroidDemo that = this;
    final String hyp = b.getString("hyp");

    that.edit_text.post(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            that.edit_text.setText(hyp);
                if(hyp.contains("COLOR BLACK")){

                bg.setImageResource(R.drawable.black);

                }
                if(hyp.contains("COLOR WHITE")){
                    bg.setImageResource(R.drawable.white);

                }
```

I am pretty new at this (only started learning programing a few months ago) so I might be missing something obvious. If you can see my error please explain.
If I in the OnPartial should use something other than .contains then what? I have tried .equals("KEY WORD") but that only works in the OnResult.

Kind regards Jakob

Edith: "Some mistakes and the code"

Edith 2: "Figured out part of previous question"

Comment: > I get a error on thread-10, a null-pointerexception. you should get a full exception stack trace. Full stacktrace can give you a more definite answer on what is going wrong. Most likely you didn't initialize some variable properlyl.

Comment: I corrected that one. Do you know how to clear the hyp after OnPartial has caught a command? Changed my question a few minutes ago.

Comment: I figured it out. I of cause need to use the .EndsWith("KEY WORD") in the OnPartial. I am such a fool! Hours spent!!

Comment: I still have a problem though. It seems that it only works for 1024 words then the app shuts down (not crashing). I have found the place in recognizertask where this is set but I don't know if it can be set to unlimited or if I still need to clear the audioq somehow. Now I won't ask only to figure it ot right after but if anyone beats me to it they are welcome to help.

Comment: @ThorDenSky I have the same problem (app just shuts down without any messages), Did you ever worked this out?